# string.split() giving memory error in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, out-of-memory

I am trying to split string but getting memory error. Is there any way to solve this or alternative solution for this?

I am getting error below code -

```
content_str = str(content_str).split('\n')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(content_str)
df1 = df1[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

Error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ravi_sir.py", line 47, in <module>
    df1 = df1[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
  File "/app/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 2001, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 2690, in split
    return self._wrap_result(result, expand=expand, returns_string=expand)
  File "/app/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 2272, in _wrap_result
    result = cons(result, columns=name, index=index, dtype=dtype)
  File "/app/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 520, in __init__
    mgr = arrays_to_mgr(arrays, columns, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/app/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py", line 93, in arrays_to_mgr
    return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)
  File "/app/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1650, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
    blocks = form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)
  File "/app/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1739, in form_blocks
    object_blocks = _simple_blockify(items_dict["ObjectBlock"], np.object_)
  File "/app/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1784, in _simple_blockify
    values, placement = _stack_arrays(tuples, dtype)
  File "/app/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 1830, in _stack_arrays
    stacked = np.empty(shape, dtype=dtype)
MemoryError
```

I am trying to read zip file from s3 bucket and saving the content into dataframe to get the total count of files inside that zip file. Creating the dataframe. My full code is given below-

```
list_table = []
for table in d:
    dict_table = OrderedDict()
    s_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print("start_time--->>",s_time)
    print("tablename--->>", table)
    
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    key='raw/vs-1/load-1619/data' +'/'+ table
    obj = s3.Object('********',key)
    n = obj.get()['Body'].read()
    gzipfile = BytesIO(n)
    gzipfile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=gzipfile)
    content = gzipfile.read()
    #print(content)
    content_str = content.decode('utf-8')
    content_str = str(content_str).split('\n')
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(content_str)
    df1 = df1[0].str.split(',', expand=True)
    #df1 = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in str(content_str).split('\n')])
    #print(df1)
    #count = os.popen('aws s3 cp s3://itx-agu-lake/raw/vs-1/load-1619/data/{0} - | wc -l'.format(table)).read()
    count = int(len(df1)) - 2
    del(df1)
    e_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    print("End_time---->>",e_time)
    
    print(count)
    dict_table['Table_Name'] = str(table)
    dict_table['Count'] = count
    list_table.append(dict_table)
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to accomplish and provide a sample of your data?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are splitting a huge string using a df column, then deleting the df, looks like you only need the count of commas for each row.  So get the count, which is simple, rather than splitting the df -- which could generate a huge amount of columns and therefore cause your memory error.

```
row1list = ['1,2,3,4']
row2list = ['5,6']
row3list = ['7,8,9']
df = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list, row3list], columns=['col'])

df['count_commas'] = df['col'].str.count(',')

print(df)
#        col  count_commas
# 0  1,2,3,4             3
# 1      5,6             1
# 2    7,8,9             2
```